# Unidentifiable cable socket

Tags: connector, identification, plug, cable-assemblies, socket

Hi looking for a manufacture part ID which matches the socket in the pictures attached.

[image]

Measurements are:-
inner black plastic diameter 12.5 mm
outer metal case 14 mm
metal screw nut (for connecting to the plug) 16 mm

It is a 3 pin connector with '1 2 3' written on the inner black plastic to identify the pins.

[image]

There are screw attachments for fixing each of the parts together. One is located under the metal screw nut. The other two are located to hold the cable grip together.
[image]

I have identified it to be a circular cable connector with an P68 SGS rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.newark.com/pro-signal/psg01589/socket-multipole-3way/dp/24M6402?ost=1280755) is a link to this connector on newark. According to them, the manufacturer is pro-signal and the part number is PSG01589. However, it seems that they are not the only manufacturers.

Comment: just checked out your link, it definitely looks like the part. I'll be ordering in a sample. Thank you for your help :-D Thanks for your help too @Michael but comparing the DIN to the one in the pictures I have to agree with Sweber

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain that this is a "circular DIN" connector as manufactured by many. Here is a [link to the Amphenol line](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/18/40_c091_abd_e-75918.pdf).

Comment: My gut feeling doesn't readily agree that it's DIN.  For instance, all connectors in the Amphenol datasheet have collet-type strain relief.  But the plug in question has a clamp-type strain relief (simpler and older design, not that that's worse).

Comment: I know this connector, and it definitively is NOT a DIN connector